# flutter splash screen didn't show

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

i have a book for flutter beginner programmer. At the first section it show me how to create splash screen, but the problem is that splash screen is doesn't show, just a blank black screen and after that the apps is showing.

This is my splash_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:wisata_yogya/main.dart';

void main() =>runApp(SplashScreen());

// ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: _SplashScreenBody(),
    );
  }
}

class _SplashScreenBody extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return _SplashScreenBodyState();
  }
}

class _SplashScreenBodyState extends State<_SplashScreenBody>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), (){
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, 
      // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()), (Route route) => false);
    });

    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage("graphics/logo.png"),
          height: 75,
          width: 75,
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

And there's no error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add timer in initState instead of what you doing something like this

```
void initState() {  
    super.initState();  
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5),  
            ()=>Navigator.pushReplacement(context,  
            MaterialPageRoute(builder:  
                (context) => HomeScreen()  
            )  
         )  
    );  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

You can use [`animated_splash_screen`](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_splash_screen) its easy to use,

```
home: AnimatedSplashScreen(
    splash: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/logo.png',
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    duration: 100,
    nextScreen: Login(),
    splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
```

**Method 2**

Or Use `Timer` for delay some seconds in the `initState()`

```
Timer(
      Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage())));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3),
            ()=>Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                (context) =>First()
            )
        )
    );
  }

 return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Image.asset('Assets/Group.png'),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
            ),
            CircularProgressIndicator(color: HexColor('#22178F'),),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```